# how to plot two graphs on ltspice on the same y scale?

Tags: ltspice, plot

i want to plot more than one graph on ltspice , the first one shows the voltage vout according to vin , and the second one the derivative of vout to vin , but it shows the two graphs on two different scales on ltspice .. how can i combine them ? any help

[image]

i want to get something like this :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the derivative of a voltage, it will be plotted as `V/s`. The solution to bring the resulting waveform to `V` is to simply multiply by `1s`:

[image: sec]

The same goes for any other waveform. For example, bringing `W` to `V` means dividing by `1A`.

Comment: this didn't work ! still shows me two diffrent y scales .. just added s next to the second scale

Comment: i updated the question to see what i am looking for ..

Comment: @jasmin Then you either have different quantities plotted (in whih case you should apply the second part of the answer), or you are doing it wrong, because the picture I posted clearly shows it is possible. Hint: look at the label of the blue trace. It is a simple matter of converting one unit of measurement to another.

Comment: but in the second picture i posted you can see the didn't conert to any units ,, and i did exactly the same thing

Comment: @jasmin No, I can't see, because the picture is of low resolution. But I can deduce that in the picture there are only voltages being plotted, which probably means that the derivative was calculated inside the schematic, and plotted from there. Even if this is not the case, what I say remains true, and, if you pay attention to what you are doing, you can do it, too.

Comment: how can i calculate the derivative inside the schematic ?

Comment: because i tried what you suggested the first time and it didn't work :'

Comment: @jasmin Let's take it from the beginning. You plot a voltage, then you plot its derivative by using the builtin waveform arithmetic function `d()`. What units of measurement are you getting for the derivative? `V/s`? Others?

Comment: how to know the units ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86680/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-jasmin).

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the axis and adjust the settings to be the same numerically, but they should not be on the same axis because the units are different.

Comment: they are already on the same axis .. i want them to be on the same y .. thats why in the first place we divided by 10 so we could show the two graphs on the same scale